# HTML parsing: How to find the image in the document, which is surrounded by most text?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xpath, html-parsing, nokogiri, mechanize

I am writing a news scraper, which has to determine the main image (thumbnail), given an HTML document of a news article.

In other words, it's basically the same challenge: [How does Facebook determine which images to show as thumbnails when posting a link?](http://www.quora.com/Facebook-1/How-does-Facebook-determine-which-images-to-show-as-thumbnails-when-posting-a-link)

There are many useful techniques (preferring higher dimensions, smaller ratio, etc.), but sometimes after parsing a web page the program ends up with a list of similar size images (half of which are ads) and it needs to pick just one, which illustrates the story described in the document.

Visually, when you open [a random news article](http://www.nytimes.com/2012/10/07/magazine/mitt-romney.html?hp&_r=0), the main picture is almost always at the top and surrounded by text. How do I implement an HTML parser (for example, using xpath / nokogiri), which finds such an image?

Comment: How well does the algorithm 'pick the largest image' fare?

Answer (score 1):

There is no good way to determine this from code unless you have pre-knowledge about the site's layout.

HTML and DHTML allow you to position elements all over the page, either using CSS or JavaScript, and can do it after the page has loaded, which is inaccessible to Nokogiri.

You *might* be able to do it using one of the Watir APIs after the page has fully loaded, however, again, you really need to know what layout a site uses. Ads can be anywhere in the HTML stream and moved around the page after loading, and the real content can be loaded dynamically and its location and size can be changed on the fly. As a result, you can't count on the position of the content in the HTML being significant, nor can you count on the content being in the HTML. JavaScript or CSS are NOT your friends in this.

When I wrote spiders and crawlers for site analytics, I had to deal with the same problem. Because I knew what sites I was going to look at, I'd do a quick pre-scan and find my landmark tags, then write some CSS or XPath accessors for those. Save those with the URLs in a database, and you can quickly fly through the pages, accurately grabbing what you want.

Without some idea of the page layout your code is completely at the mercy of the page-layout people, and anything that modifies the page's element's locations.

Basically, you need to implement the wet-ware inside your brain in code, along with the ability to render the page graphically so your code can analyze it. When you, as a user, view a page in your browser, you are using visual and contextual clues to locate the significant content. All that contextual information is what's missing and what you'll need to write.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, your problem lies less with parsing the page, but with implementing a logic that successfully decides which image to select.

The first step I think is to decide, which images are news images and which are not (ads for example).

You can find that out by reading the image URL (src-attibute of the image-tag) and checking th host against the article host the middle part ("nytimes" in your example) should be the same.

The second step is to decide which of these is the most important one. For that you can use image size in article, position on page, etc. For step 2 you would have to try out what works best, for most sites. tweak your algorithm, until it produces the best results for most news sites.

Hope this helps